# Linear Transformation defined by orthogonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $T : \Bbb{R}^3 →\Bbb{R}^3$ be a linear transformation given by the formula $T(x,y,z) = A(x, y, z)^t $where $ A$ is a $3×3$ real orthogonal matrix of determinant $1$. Then
A)$ T$ is an isometry of $\mathbb{R}^3$.
B) the matrix of $T$ with respect to the usual basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $A^t$
C) the eigenvalues of $T$ are either $1$ or $−1$
D) $T$ is surjective.

I can only say that option a is true because
$(x, y, z) A^t A (x, y, z) ^t$=$x^2 + y^2 +z^2$ =$(x, y, z). (x, y, z) ^t$

Comment: C is actually false. See the comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think B) is false because $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^3$ is represented by $A$ so the matrix $A$ representing it maps the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ to another set of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ not $A^t$. In fact, I think $A^t = A^{-1}$ since $A$ is orthogonal.

C) is false since if there is an eigenvalue we have $Av = \lambda v$. We also know that $|Av|^2 = \lambda^2|v|^2 = (Av)^t(Av) = v^tA^tAv$. Now since $A$ is orthogonal, $A^tA = I$ so $v^tA^tAv = v^tv = |v|^2$ Therefore, we get $\lambda^2|v|^2 = |v|^2$ so $|\lambda| = 1$. However this only shows that the magnitude of the eigenvalues is 1 not that they equal $\pm 1$. The eigenvalues could be complex as said in the comments below in the case of an orthogonal rotation matrix.

Not sure about D)

Comment: I don't think C) is true. You seem to be assuming that $\lambda$ is real, but the eigenvalues could very well be complex. So I think you've only shown that $|\lambda| = 1$. For example, consider a rotation matrix like $\begin{pmatrix} \cos t & -\sin t & 0\\ \sin t & \cos t & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$, which will typically have complex eigenvalues, for instance when $t = \pi/2$.

Comment: @RichardD.James You're right I forgot about complex eigenvalues. Rotation matrices are orthogonal and can have them.

Answer (score 1):

After mihirb's answer.

Option D) is true.
$A$ has determinant $1\neq0$, so $A$ has full rank, so $T$ is surjective.

Option B) is false, because the matrix representation will be $A$ not $A^t$.

Comment: Please explain why the matrix representation is A?

Comment: Just try to find the matrix representation $T$ with respect to $\{(1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ by taking $A=(a_{ij})$. it is very easy. It has nothing to do with orthogonal property of $A$.

Comment: Yes, but to calculate that I have to know A. But I only know that $A$ is orthogonal. Elements of $A$ are unknown. I think the matrix representation of $A$ with respect to the standard basis will be a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are that of $A$. Am I correct? Please rectify me if not.

Comment: No. I said take $A=(a_{ij})$ and try to find the matrix representation. If you still can't then comment.

Comment: It is very clear to me now. Thanks a lot gentleman.